# bootstrap tags-input display value using jquery not shown

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, bootstrap-tags-input

Can someone help me with bootstrap tags input? I'm using laravel I have created a modal, these are my codes I just want to display the value inside the input text. After I put data-role="tagsinput" it will style="display:none".Is this kind of method getting the value like that is possible in bootstrap tags-input?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="email">To:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-role="tagsinput" id="email" name="email" >
        <p class="errorEmail text-center alert alert-danger hidden"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$('#email').val($(this).data('email'));`

Comment: Instead of providing the images for the code, Kindly write the sample code in the post itself.

Comment: sorry for that I'm new to post codes.